# D3 Y-axis text Copy/Paste to Excel

Tags: excel, d3.js, svg, clipboard, axis

I have a horizontal bar chart SVG element created from reading in a .CSV using D3.

The Y-axis contains ~200 "project" text labels next to each horizontal bar.

I would like the user to be able to select a block or all the projects on the Y-axis and copy and paste into excel.

Currently, when everything is copy-pasted into excel, all the labels just appear as one long string of text.  Is there a way to add a hidden comma/new line to the label that will allow it to be pasted in excel?

This is my first question on here, sorry if this doesn't make sense.

[I want the user be able to copy and paste these y-labels into Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdvPu.png)

Comment: `Paste Special... | Text` seems to work.

Comment: It sure does, I can communicate to the end users to use paste special, but is there any way to code it to copy as text by default?